# Non-zero torsion manifold affine connection properties

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In a manifold with non-zero torsion, how can I show that

$T_{b\hspace{2mm}c}^{\hspace{1mm}a} = - T_{bc}^{\hspace{2mm}a}$

where
$T^b_{\hspace{1mm}ac} \equiv \Gamma^b_{\hspace{1mm}ac} - \Gamma^b_{\hspace{1mm}ca}$

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried to prove it yourself? Actually, it is very easy to show this just from the definition that is written in the post.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do it, but I cannot find the solution. Do you have any idea on how to prove it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Since the only thing you can work with is the definition of ${T^b}_{ca}$, try to start from ${{T_b}^a}_c$ and raise/lower indices with the metric so as to have something like ${T^\square}_{\square\square}$. Be careful to name differently every index you introduce.
2. Notice from the definition that the torsion is antisymmetric in the last two indices. So try to interchange indices in the result you got after raising/lowering and get a minus sign out.
3. Finally revert the raising/lowering: ${T^\square}_{\square\square}\longrightarrow {T_{bc}}^a$.